# How to delete table entry by event?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two client-linked tables and contacts.

Customer table fields:
IDCOMPANY,ADRESS,HP,WEBSITE

ContactName table fields:
CONTACTNAMEID,EMAIL,CUSTOMERSID,PHONE

I made a form to search for the linked contacts for each client and delete them.
The search works.
Deleting I get an error.

The sub form is qsubform

```vb
Private Sub btnDelete_Click()

    If Not (Me.qsubform.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.qsubform.Form.Recordset.EOF) Then
 
        If MsgBox("sure?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    
            CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM ContactName" & _
              "WHERE CustomersId=" & Me.qsubform.Form.Recordset.Fields("CustomersId")
    
            Me.qsubform.Form.Requery
    
        End If
    
    End If
```

Comment: You are missing a space between your `ContactName` and `WHERE` words. Change it to `" WHERE `

Comment: Thanks!!!now works.Such little nonsense.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```vb
Private Sub btnDelete_Click()
   If Not (Me.qsubform.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.qsubform.Form.Recordset.EOF) Then
      If MsgBox("sure?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
         CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM ContactName" & _
" WHERE CustomersId=" & Me.qsubform.Form.Recordset.Fields("CustomersId") & ";"
         Me.qsubform.Form.Requery
      End If
End If
```

Comment: **CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE Customers SET COMPANY='" & Me.txtComapny & _

"',ADRESS ='" & Me.txtAdress & _

"',HP ='" & Me.txtHp & _

"',WEBSITE ='" & Me.txtWebsite & _

"', WHERE CUSTOMERSID =" & Val(Me.txtId)
**


similr mistake when i try to update data..missing a space?

Comment: In that one, there should be no comma (`,`) before `WHERE`.